# Why am I getting Post method error while submitting form in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-urls

This is the error which i m getting when trying to click on the submit button:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/contact/
Using the URLconf defined in career.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
myapp/
signup
/contact
^media/(?P\<path\>.\*)$
The current path, contact/, didn’t match any of these.
```

Contact.html:

```
<div class="container my-3">
<h1>Contact Admin</h1>
<form method="post" action="/contact">
{% csrf_token %}
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" aria-describedby="name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" aria-        describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone     else.</small>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="phone">Phone Number</label>
    <input type="phone" class="form-control" name="phone" id="phone">
  </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="content">How may we help you?</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" name="content" id="content" cols="30" rows="3"></textarea>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
</div>
```

views.py:

```
def contact(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    name = request.POST['name']
    email = request.POST['email']
    phone = request.POST['phone']
    content = request.POST['content']
    print(name, email, phone, content)
    contact.save()
return render(request, "myapp/contact.html")
```

models.py:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
sno = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
phone = models.CharField(max_length=10)
email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
content = models.TextField()

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import\*

admin.site.register(Careers)
admin.site.register(Contact)
```

project urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = \[
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('myapp/', include('myapp.urls')),
path('signup', include('myapp.urls')),
path('/contact', include('myapp.urls')),

\] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

app urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from .import views

urlpatterns = \[
path("",views.index,name="CareerHome"),
path("about/",views.about,name="AboutUs"),
path("careers/\<int:myid\>",views.careers,name="Careers"),
path("aptitude/",views.aptitude,name="Aptitude"),
path("feedback/",views.feedback,name="Feedback"),
path("contact/",views.contact,name="Contact"),
path('signup',views.handleSignup,name="handleSignup"),
\]
```

I feel like I need to do changes in urls file of my main project. I tried changing it a few times but it still gives me the same error or else it takes me to home page without any data being saved in my database.

what changes should i do in my urls file of both project and app to resolve this error?

Comment: remove the trailing slash. You did not add any trailing slash on your urlpatterns. should be like this http://127.0.0.1:8000/contact (without trailing slash)

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing is related to how you've set up your URL patterns in your Django project. The problem is in your project's `urls.py` file where you're including the URL patterns for the `/contact` route.

Here's the problematic line in your project's `urls.py`:

```py
path('/contact', include('myapp.urls')),
```

In Django's `path()` function, you should not include a leading slash before the route. The correct way to define this URL pattern should be:

```py
path('contact/', include('myapp.urls')),
```

Notice that I've removed the leading slash before `contact`.

Once you make this change, your `urls.py` in the project should look like this:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('myapp/', include('myapp.urls')),
    path('signup/', include('myapp.urls')),
    path('contact/', include('myapp.urls')),  # Corrected URL pattern

] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

With this correction, the URL patterns should match properly and the `contact` view in your `myapp` should be accessible via the `/contact/` URL.